# Special Characters allowed when SharePoint List in List Url

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

Are there any set of Special characters that are not allowed when the list is created and the url is generated for the same. 
For e.g. When i create  list say `A&B` the url when generated for the list does strip the `&` from it. Do we have anything documentation which lets us know that certain number of special case characters are not allowed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this: [Acceptable characters in SPList 'title' fields](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cc7d401c-5f2d-49e9-afea-c2bf42368fd0/acceptable-characters-in-splist-title-fields?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

> Every List should match to an unique directory with a full url path.
>
> When you create a new list, SharePoint will assign the name of
> directory based the value of the title.  The name of the directory can
> only include non-special characters like 0-9,a-Z  and “*”, but the
> character “*” can’t be as starting.
>
> The list name/title is the same as your typed.
>
> If the list title include the special characters, SharePoint will remove all characters.
>
> If the rest start with the “_”, this character also will be removed.
>
> The rest will be as the name of the directory.
>
> At last if the rest is blank, the name will be replaced
> by “list”, if the “list” existed, use the “list1” and so on.

From this: [Information about the characters that you cannot use in site names, folder names, and file names in SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/905231/information-about-the-characters-that-you-cannot-use-in-site-names,-fo)

Section "Folder Names"

You cannot use the following characters anywhere in a folder name or a server name:

- Tilde
- Number sign
- Percent
- Ampersand
- Asterisk
- Braces
- Backslash
- Colon
- Angle brackets
- Question mark
- Slash
- Pipe
- Quotation mark

You cannot use the period character consecutively in the middle of a folder name.

You cannot use the period character at the end of a folder name.

You cannot start a folder name with a period character.

If you use an underscore character (_) at the beginning of a folder name, the folder will be a hidden folder.

Additionally, a folder that contains the string "*vti*" is reserved by SharePoint, and isn’t supported.

Answer (score 2):

The disallowed characters are [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Invalid-characters-in-file-or-folder-names-or-invalid-file-types-in-OneDrive-for-Business-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa). As long as the name or url doesn't have these you should be good.

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 2):

Please refer this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/905231/information-about-the-characters-that-you-cannot-use-in-site-names,-fo). It will help you.

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)